# How to get number rows updated/added when we make DB call via JCA files in osb proxy service

Tags: datasource, osb, jca

I am as a client inserting/updating/fetching values to/from back-end DB via JCA files creating business service and making the call. I am facing problem while performing insert/update call as for all the request i will be getting success response irrespective of the DB getting added/updated. If there is a way to confirm like these many rows got updated after insert/update DB then it confirms like operation is successful.

Below is the simple JCA file to update the DB, can you please let me know what extra configuration i need to do to get the number of rows get updated..!

```
<adapter-config name="RetrieveSecCustRelationship" adapter="Database Adapter" wsdlLocation="RetrieveSecCustRelationship.wsdl" xmlns="http://platform.integration.oracle/blocks/adapter/fw/metadata">

  <connection-factory location="eis/DB/Database" UIConnectionName="Database" adapterRef=""/>
  <endpoint-interaction portType="RetrieveSecCustRelationship_ptt" operation="RetrieveSecCustRelationship">
    <interaction-spec className="oracle.tip.adapter.db.DBPureSQLInteractionSpec">
      <property name="SqlString" value=**"update CUSTOMER_INSTALLED_PRODUCT set CUSTOMER_ID=? where CUSTOMER_ID=?"**/>
      <property name="GetActiveUnitOfWork" value="false"/>
      <property name="QueryTimeout" value="6"/>
    </interaction-spec>
    <input/>
    <output/>
  </endpoint-interaction>

</adapter-config>
```

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will need to wrap it in PL/SQL and then extend that PL/SQL so number of affected rows is being returned. Then you could extract this value from response variable with XPath.

Comment: thanks for your reply piotr, if i wrap PL/SQL then the JCA file states as invalid, if you hav any example then please share it.

Comment: you need to regenerate your JCA adapter

Comment: can you please show one example, or the property name to add in the JCA file, i have given above the JCA file which i am using, can you tell where exactly i need to make changes.. !

Comment: Maybe I was not precise enough, I meant create DB package with PL/SQL procedure and call that procedure from OSB.